# cordova build android - not wroking

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins

when i run `cordova buidld android` it is showing below error

```
Android Studio project detected
ANDROID_HOME=/home/vishal/Android/Sdk
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
studio
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/jni/libnative-platform-curses.so: undefined symbol: tgetent
(node:5864) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: /usr/share/gradle/bin/gradle: Command failed with exit code 127
(node:5864) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cause:

You try to use openjdk instead of oracle-jdk. Probably because openjdk is set as default JDK in your OS.  You can verify this by typing:

```
java -version
```

Solution:

Set proper JAVA_HOME environment variable and retry gradle task.